# Is there any performance gain from CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, ado.net, sqldatareader

I realized I always read my fields in the order they are returned by index (using constants). So my code is already compatible with CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess as far as i understand.

Would there be any benefits if i turn it on? DataReader is already forward only, read only which is the real performance gain right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main usage of this is when you are reading very large CLOB (`nvarchar(max)` etc) or BLOB (`varbinary(max)`) fields. In the default usage, it buffers the entire row of data before letting you near it - which could mean it has to allocate a large buffer for any BLOB / CLOB fields. When using sequential mode, it *does not buffer the row*; you can use the regular API for small fields (as long as you access them in the correct order), but for the CLOB / BLOB fields you can use the chunk-based APIs ([`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`GetChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getchars(v=vs.110).aspx)) to access fractions of the data in turn. By doing this you could, for example, process a 40 MB image using only a 1k or 4k buffer.

[MSDN says the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides a way for the DataReader to handle rows that contain columns with large binary values. Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream. You can then use the GetBytes or GetChars method to specify a byte location to start the read operation, and a limited buffer size for the data being returned.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it - a buffer of 8040 bytes (or a multiple of that) would be normal here. IIRC, since the page size in SQL Server is 8040, you tend to get optimal results if you work to complete pages.

Comment: If a **FileStream** is being used for the BLOB, will the SQL page size for a buffer still be a consideration?  My understanding is that the file contents are stored on the NTFS file system.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is supposed to be at least some performance gain for using **CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess**, even when not accessing BLOBs. The Microsoft KB article, 
[An "Invalid attempt to read from column ordinal" error occurs when you use DataReader in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308614/an-invalid-attempt-to-read-from-column-ordinal-error-occurs-when-you-use-datareader-in-visual-c), states:

> Setting the CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess flag causes the **DataReader** to read both rows and columns sequentially. The rows and columns are not buffered. After you read past a column, it is dropped from memory. Any attempt to re-read the column or read previously read columns results in an exception.
>
> Using the **CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess** flag provides a performance benefit, especially when using Binary Large Object (BLOB) fields. If you do not use **SequentialAccess**, all the BLOB data is copied to the client. This can consume a lot of resources.
>
> **CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess** also improves performance when accessing non-BLOB fields. When **CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess** is not set, you can access a column out of order; however, you incur the following overhead:
>
> - The column is checked to see if the column is later than a previous accessed column.
> - The data for all of the previously accessed columns is retrieved and then cached for potential later retrieval.
>
> Columns must be checked and cached because when you use the **DataReader**, the underlying stream is forward-only for rows as well as column access.

Comment: My team measured a 2X performance improvement on all reader based access. Our data access layer code is set up to always enforce sequential reads and explicit column order.  If you do that, this option should be the default behavior.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MatthewHazzard That's awesome! Yeah, I can't think of a reason to _not_ use SequentialAccess. It's pretty rare to need to go back and forth between columns, unless, I suppose, if you always access them via column name, in which case that could easily be out of order. Glad it helped, and thanks for sharing how it worked for you.