# File Corrupted when reading a BLOB object from an SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

All, can someone assist.

I have problems while reading a BLOB object in SQL DB. The file download but cannot open due to file being corrupted. Error appears with any document type (pdf, docx, jpg, etc).

The code executes a Stored Procedure which fetches the binary based on two different parameters.

Here is the code:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Request.QueryString["docid"].ToString(); 
        //string DocumentID = Request.QueryString["DocumentID"].ToString();
        string DocumentID = "9163736c-8064-11e8-ab16-2c44fd826130";
        string SessionId = "91494483-8064-11e8-ab16-2c44fd826130";
        //Connection and Parameters
        SqlParameter param1 = null;
        SqlParameter param2 = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProcessManagerConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getdoc", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        param1 = new SqlParameter("@DocumentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param2 = new SqlParameter("@SessionId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param1.Value = DocumentID;
        param2.Value = SessionId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        //Open connection and fetch the data with reader
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader =
          cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            //
            string doctype = reader["Extension"].ToString();
            string docname = reader["Docname"].ToString();
            //
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = doctype;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                     "attachment; filename=" + docname);
            //
            //Code for streaming the object while writing
            const int ChunkSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            byte[] binary = (reader["Data"]) as byte[];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binary);
            int SizeToWrite = ChunkSize;

            for (int i = 0; i < binary.GetUpperBound(0) - 1; i = i + ChunkSize)
            {
                if (!Response.IsClientConnected) return;
                if (i + ChunkSize >= binary.Length)
                    SizeToWrite = binary.Length - i;
                byte[] chunk = new byte[SizeToWrite];
                ms.Read(chunk, 0, SizeToWrite);
                Response.BinaryWrite(chunk);
                Response.Flush();
            }
            Response.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do any chunking here. You already have the binary data loaded into memory. Just make a single call to:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(binary);
```

Avoid creating `MemoryStream` and whatnot. I have a feeling there is a bug with your chunking code.

If you are looking to reduce the memory usage in your app when streaming binary data, you should look into using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`.

Lastly, I prefer to handle this type of thing using a simple  `System.Web.IHttpHandler` (ASHX) over an `System.Web.UI.Page` (ASPX).

Try creating a file called `HectorsHandler.ashx` with the following content:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="HectorsApp.HectorsHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

namespace HectorsApp
{
    public class HectorsHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctxt)
        {
            // Request.QueryString["docid"].ToString(); 
            //string DocumentID = Request.QueryString["DocumentID"].ToString();
            string DocumentID = "9163736c-8064-11e8-ab16-2c44fd826130";
            string SessionId = "91494483-8064-11e8-ab16-2c44fd826130";
            //Connection and Parameters
            SqlParameter param1 = null;
            SqlParameter param2 = null;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProcessManagerConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getdoc", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                param1 = new SqlParameter("@DocumentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                param2 = new SqlParameter("@SessionId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param1.Value = DocumentID;
                param2.Value = SessionId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
                //Open connection and fetch the data with reader
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //
                        string doctype = reader["Extension"].ToString();
                        string docname = reader["Docname"].ToString();
                        //
                        ctxt.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                        ctxt.Response.Buffer = false;
                        ctxt.Response.ContentType = doctype;
                        ctxt.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docname);

                        //Code for streaming the object while writing
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8040];
                        long dataIndex = 0;
                        while (ctxt.Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            long bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(reader.GetOrdinal("Data"), dataIndex, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (bytesRead == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            ctxt.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
                            ctxt.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                            dataIndex += bytesRead;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

Per the comments below, there is no longer need to clear any data since you now have full control over what is being output.

Note that because `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` is being used, columns must be read in order.

[Is there any performance gain from CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895047/315689)

Comment: Hi Dana. I have implemented the code as you have posted it and I get the same results. It does download but the file is corrupted and it cannot be opened. One issue with the code is the very last line. ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()  produces the following error and I cannot shake it off: "The name 'ApplicationInstance' does not exist in the current context" Thank you

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, but you can use `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead. Are you sure the file is not be corrupt during upload? If you open the download in a text editor, can you see extra characters toward the bottom?

Comment: Hi Dana. Context. took care of the error. The web app i'm putting together will replace an out-of-license ticketing system. So using the soon to be gone interface the same file downloads fine so it is not corrupted during upload. When download using my or your suggested code the file download and if opened in a text editor you see all kinds of characters and the name of the file included. the only odd thing is that the corrupted file is a few kb smaller than the working file. some compression issues on the way down? example: working PDF file = 789 KB. Corrupted PDF file = 611 KB

Comment: Dana, right after I wrote the above i went ahead and simply renamed the file to xxx.ZIP, double clicked and it worked. So the files are compressed at source. I need to then rename the file .zip or decompress it at download... any thoughts? your help is much appreciated

Comment: You probably have GZIP enabled and the call to `ClearHeaders` is erasing some header.

Comment: Dana, for the time being your code is working when added .zip to the downloaded file. I'll look into what kind compression software is enabled on my box. ***`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docname + ".zip");`*** Thanks for providing the answer

Comment: Thanks Hector - I made 1 final updated where I moved the code into an ASHX handler which prevents us from having to clear any data or terminate the request early.

Comment: Dana, much appreciated. I will give that a run. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174731/discussion-between-dana-and-hector-marcia).