Fetch Image from database by SQL query it takes too much time
I am trying to get data from my SQL Server database by using a SQL query. Now, when I run the query in SQL Server then without image column, 1462 rows of data are retrieved within a second. When I run the same query with the image, then the same data output takes 30+ seconds.
Table: Stock
Columns:
ID (AutoIncrement by 1)
Name (varchar(50))
DesignImage (varbinary(MAX))

Without DesignImage query
select Name from Stock

I get output of 1462 rows of data within a second.
With DesignImage query
Select Name, DesignImage from Stock

I get output of 1462 rows of data in 30+ seconds.
Is there any issue with the image column? Or any way in short time image column also filter.
Thank you.

Save the images on the file system or a server. Then store the path/url and remove the image column. Problem solved.

@JonasMetzler how can I save image file in server and get related file path?

Getting text data for ~1,500 rows and getting text and image data for 1,500 rows is vastly different. The size of the amount of data to glbe obtained will be significantly larger for the latter. As such it's not surprising that it takes longer to obtain that data.

What is the reason of having images stored in SQL? And what is their average size (in Kb/Mb)?

Try CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895047/5045688 and docs: 1, 2.

See Compare Options for Storing Blobs (SQL Server). Consider using FILESTREAM or FileTables.

Also see SqlClient Streaming Support

Images are usually very big (as in megabytes) while text is usually small (kilobytes). Reading large amounts of data from any database takes a long time. If every image is 1 MB then you're fetching 1.5 GB over the network. If your have a GBit network, that alone will take at least 15 seconds. On top of that, the database server has to load that much from disk which also takes a couple of seconds.
Run a query that sums the lengths of the data in the DesignImage column to get an idea about the real numbers.
Without any knowledge what problem you try to solve, there is no way to make this faster. But I can give you a few hints:

Try to query the name only until you know which images you really need and then fetch only those specific images.
Use paging to fetch the images in batches. That will take even longer but the recipient can start using the first image faster.
Most SQL databases have a syntax to get a stream instead of the image as pure bytes. That way, you just get a handle to the image data. If you don't read anything from that handle, this will be cheap. Check your database manual for "streaming large binary data".

